# Why is $0 not -bash in an interactive login shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I was reading about bash interactive and on interactive logins and found that running bash with `-l` option will start it as login shell but after doing so, when I ran command `echo $0` to verify, it still shows as non login shell.

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash -l
[root@localhost ~]# echo $0
bash
```

It should show `-` as prefix to shell name. Please confirm if I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have an `-` as the first character of the command name is just one way to signal a login shell, there are other signals. In fact, the correct way to detect that the present shell is a login shell is to ask the shell itself.

In the bash manual:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.

In bash:

```
shopt -p login_shell
```

Will print `-u` if the shell is not login, and `-s` if it is.

Lets test it:

```
$ ln -s $(which bash) ./-bash       # make a local copy of bash
$ PATH=$PATH:.                      # Big security problem, don't use it.
$ -bash                             # start the local copy of bash
$ echo $0                           # Its name start with an -
-bash                               
$ shopt -p login_shell              # Is it a login shell?
shopt -s login_shell                # Yes!, the answer is -s

$ exit                              # leave the login shell
$ PATH=${PATH%:.}                   # Remove the local pwd from the path.
$ rm ./-bash                        # Remove the local copy of bash
```

In fact, that $0 has a - doesn't have to mean that the shell is a login shell:

```
$  bash -c 'echo $0; shopt -p login_shell' -bash 1 2 3
-bash
shopt -u login_shell
```

The other way (from the manual) to get a login shell, is just ask for it:

```
$ bash --login                 # ask for a login shell
$ echo $0                      # What is its name?
bash
$ shopt -p login_shell         # Is it a login shell?
shopt -s login_shell           # Yes, it is!

$ exit                         # leave the login shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

A login shell can be one of two below:

1- whose first character of argument zero is ‘-’

2- one invoked with the --login option

```
> echo $0
=if=> -bash # login shell.
=if=> bash  # we don't know nothing!!!
> shopt -p login_shell
=if=> shopt -s login_shell # login shell.
=if=> shopt -u login_shell # non-login shell
```

another way (which is an ugly one!) is to exit from the current shell, if your shell is logged_in one, the output will be logout, if not it will be simply just exit:

```
> bash
> shopt -p login_shell
shopt -u login_shell
> exit
exit # it says exit

> bash -l
> shopt -p login_shell
shopt -s login_shell
> exit
logout # it says logout
```

and you CAN NOT `logout` from a non-login shell